# How to save state when activity it destroyed with this

Tags: android

```
    public class Talk extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog progDialog;
int typeBar;
TextView text1;
EditText edit;
Button respond;
private String name;
private String textAtView;
private String savedName;

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dorothydialog);


    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog);
    edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.repsond);
    respond = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);

    respond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text1.setText("Welcome! Enter your name!");

            respond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    name = edit.getText().toString();

                    text1.setText("Cool! your name is "+name);

                }
            });

        }
    });

}
```

}

Okay so i want to figure out how i would save the state of this activity. this is just a small snippet from my code to show you guys an example. So i want to save the state so when the activity is destroyed the user will come back where they left off.
Second thing, I would like to show a quick 5 second Progress dialog spinner between each button click.

Comment: [This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) explains the Application/Activity lifecycles and their callback methods, and [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState) explains saving persistent state. Second thing, do you really want a 5 second progress dialog spinner between each button click? Or would you rather have a 5 second portion of time where user input is suspended?

Answer (score 1):

For the second thing

This should work:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements Runnable, OnClickListener {
private TextView tv;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv);     
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    tv.setText("initial text");

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(TestActivity.this, "Please wait...", "Details here", true, false);

    Thread thread = new Thread(TestActivity.this);
    thread.start();
}
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        pd.dismiss();
        tv.setText("text after 5 sec passed");
    }
};
}
```

Comment: The only thing is now i want the runDialog() to show before the text is show on the textView in my method above.

Comment: so just call runDialog(); before textView.setText();

Comment: I did that but it still does it together.